# I can't use telemetrygen to generate traces to Grafana tempo

Tags: grafana, trace, observability, tempo

It's my first time to use Grafana tempo.I just follow official documentation to configured my tempo in k8s cluster with helm.And I can successfully configure tempo in Grafana platform Like this:
[image]

[image]

then I use telemetrygen and Grafana agent to generate some test traces to tempo, but I failed:

```
telemetrygen traces --otlp-insecure --rate 20 --duration 5s grafana-agent.tempo-test.svc.cluster.local:4317

kubectl port-forward services/grafana-agent 4317:4317 --namespace tempo-test
```

The error is:

```
Err: connection error: desc = "error reading server preface: http2: frame too large"    {"system": "grpc", "grpc_log": true}
```

[image]

The config of Grafana agent is:
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is this a programming related question?